# Bulk letter, "loop" doesn't work, "read to" doesn't work

Tags: macros, letters, article

Original Text below

Edit:
I solved it with endless googleing and help from here. Here is my theory: the typos caused `expandafter` to fail, which caused a dismatch between the `chopline` command and the rest of the chopped line of the previous loop. Another error was the `ifeof`. Latex tried to read one line after `eof`. This caused "read to" to fail

Working code:

The format of the csv must be

```
academicTitle(might be empty);surname;prename;Street+Number;ZIP-code;city;addressExtension;postbox(0 or certainValue)\n
```

File begins here:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[verbose]{placeins}


%What do we do? Delete all the margins!!! How do we do it? By force!!!
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{845pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-3.3in}
\setlength{\voffset}{-1.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{845pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{597pt}


%Personal chopline command from https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_Serienbrief_mit_externen_Daten
\def\chopline#1;#2;#3;#4;#5;#6;#7;#8 \\{
\def\Titel{#1}
\def\Name{#2}
\def\Vorname{#3}
\def\Strasse{#4}
\def\PLZ{#5}
\def\Ort{#6}
\def\Adresszusatz{#7}
\def\Postfach{#8}
}

\newif\ifmore \moretrue



\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newread\quelle
\openin\quelle=Adressen.csv %Here we get the addresses from

\loop

\read\quelle to\zeile
\ifeof\quelle
\global\morefalse
\else{

%write you stuff here

\newpage %gets ignored on first page


\expandafter\chopline\zeile\\
\vspace*{-0.02\paperwidth} %due to my Brief.pdf
\hspace*{0.0\paperheight}  %same here
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{./Brief.pdf}

\FloatBarrier
\vspace*{-0.23\paperheight} %shift the box where desired
\hspace*{0.65\paperwidth}   %same here
\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{
\Titel \ \Vorname \ \Name \ \\
\ifx\Adresszusatz\empty %if it isn't empty, it is printed
\else
\Adresszusatz \\
\fi
\ifnum\Postfach=0 %if the value is 0 in the .csv, it isn't printed
\else
Postfach \ \Postfach
\fi
\Strasse \ \\
\PLZ \ \Ort
}

%stop with you writing here

}
\fi

\ifmore\repeat

\closein\quelle


\end{document}
```

Original Question:

This is my first question. I googled a lot, but I still haven't succeeded.

I have made an automatic generator for letter envelopes. This reads from a csv-file. I stick to the instruction given in [de.wikibooks Serienbrief](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_Serienbrief_mit_externen_Daten#Beispielcode). But unfortunately it won't work.

I use Texmaker and MikTex on Windows 7, but I could change to Manjaro, if necessary.

This is my code:

```
Former code
```

It crashes after "read to". This seems to be the problem, but I ca'nt figure out why. Furthermore, the loop doesn't work in ANY way. No matter what kind of loop (`loop`, `whiledo`, `for`) I set up, it only loops once. Even if I set a for-loop to 30 repetitions. Actually it should produce 30 frames.

Don't judge me on using beamer for the envelopes. 
I would give more tags, but I'm not allowed to.

Comment: The first thing I spotted is `\Straße`, which will not work.  You have to use `\Strasse`.

Comment: Also `\NamensTitel` should be `\Titel` and `\Nachname` is `\Name`

Comment: And `value{Postfach}` should be `\Postfach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps not the best way, but somewhat 'failsafe' is using the `expl3` features and `\ior_map_inline` command that reads the file line by line and processes the input line.

I've used a sequence to split the line into the several relevant parts.

Please note, that white space must be entered with `foo\ some other stuff`!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forloop}

\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}



\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_const:Nn \c_maestro_titel_int {1}
\int_const:Nn \c_maestro_vorname_int {2}
\int_const:Nn \c_maestro_name_int {3}
\int_const:Nn \c_maestro_strasse_int {4}
\int_const:Nn \c_maestro_plz_int {5}
\int_const:Nn \c_maestro_ort_int {6}
\int_const:Nn \c_maestro_zusatz_int {7}
\int_const:Nn \c_maestro_postfach_int {8}


\ior_new:N \l_maestro_quelle_stream

\ior_open:Nn  \l_maestro_quelle_stream  {Adressen.csv}

\ior_map_inline:Nn \l_maestro_quelle_stream {%
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;} {#1}% Split the sequence
  \begin{frame}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{beeduck.jpg}\par

%    \vspace{0.6\paperheight}
%    \hspace{0.6\paperheight}????
    \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\c_maestro_titel_int}~\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\c_maestro_vorname_int}~\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\c_maestro_name_int}\par
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\c_maestro_zusatz_int}}
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_tl {%
      \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl\par
    }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\c_maestro_postfach_int}}
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_tl {%
      Postfach~\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl\par
    }
    \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\c_maestro_strasse_int}\par
    \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\c_maestro_plz_int}~\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\c_maestro_ort_int}
  \end{frame}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

And `Adressen.csv` is here:

```
;Gandalf;Stormcrow;Shireroad;10000;Shire;bei\ Schmidt;11111
;Baggins;Bilbo;Shireroad;10000;Shire;bei\ Müller;22222
Dwarf-King;Thorin;Oak-Shield;Erebor\ Road;Middle\ Earth;Arkenstone;at\ Smaug's\ cave;33333
```

[image]

Comment: Since this is a solutions, I mark this as solution, though I solved it myself.